# Hidden keyframes

Tags: keyframes

My keyframes have dissapeared, but the animations are still working.
Its not the keyframes what dissapeared. It is the "Rig" under "Summary"
So if I turn off "Only keyframes from selected area" its shows the models and its shape keys but not the rigs. I tried searching for unhide keys or select all frame all reload the blend file etc etc.

It started first when I changed to the "Nonlinear Animation" tab (I wanted to loop an animation, So I Split-ed a track)
It happened one time when I switched to Graph editor or Dope sheet I don't remember. I did not find the solution to that I just reloaded an old save.

Answer (score 0):

I figuried out. If you press "Push down action" in Nonlinear Animation your frames dissapear in every edit/view mode. But I don't know how to get back ang roup the track together again. Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I had found a similar problem and the solution is simple. Go to the action editor and back to the timeline and all the keyframes will be visible again.

Hope it helps.